# Add the suffix "_low" to all selected objects

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, obj

There is a certain number of objects and it is necessary to add the suffix "_low" to all selected objects.

[image]

The screenshot shows an example of how this is implemented in a blender and what I tried to get.

I found a similar script, but the current works with the active object.. I didn't manage to make it work for all the allocated

```
import bpy
suffix = "_low"
act_obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active

if suffix not in act_obj.name:
    act_obj.name = act_obj.name + suffix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bpy
suffix = "_low"

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    if suffix not in ob.name:
        ob.name = ob.name + suffix
```

Hope that helps!
Happy blending!